# ReactNative TextInput not visible iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I have the following stripped down render result:

```
return (
  <View style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}>
    <TextInput value={'Hello'}/>
  </View>
);
```

The generated TextInput is not visible in iOS, unless I specify the height, and when using flexDirection:'row' in its container, I need to specify its width as well.

This only happens with iOS, Android seems to work as expected.

Is there a way of displaying a TextInput in iOS without fixed size?

Current dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native": "=0.18.1",
    "react-native-orientation": "=1.12.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "=1.1.0"
  },
```

iOS:

[image]

Android:

[image]

Changing the render like this:

```
return (
  <View style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}>
    <Text>text</Text>
    <TextInput value={'Hello'}/>
  </View>
);
```

has the following result:

iOS:

[image]

Android:

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to define a height for the textInput. Try:

```
return (
  <View style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}>
    <Text>text</Text>
    <TextInput style={{ backgroundColor: '#ededed', height: 60 }} value={'Hello'}/>
  </View>
);
```

Or, if you do not want to define a height on your TextInput, you can define the height on the containing view, and flex:1 on the TextInput:

```
<View style={{ height:60 }}>
    <TextInput style={{ flex:1, backgroundColor: '#ededed' }} />
</View>
```

Comment: Yes I know it works if I do that. So it is not possible to just have it take the available space as with other elements?

Comment: Not in iOS. The only other way around it is to add a height to the container, and a `flex:1` to the TextInput. I've updated my code to show that.

Comment: May need '#ededed' instead of 'ededed' for backgroundColor.

Comment: @NaderDabit This simple solution works great. You saved my day

Comment: Thanks... saved me so much time

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue, but it rendered when I removed `alignItems:'center'` from the top most parent view in the `render()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Use `style={{ color: 'black' }}`.

This solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

when we use an TextInput in react-native the TextInput will not expand to fill the space available to it by default instead we have to add style rule that how big the TextInput should be.if your not add style for TextInput with height you cant appear the TextInput